# Segmentation Fault while trying to read from an input of characters

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why is my code for the fillArray function resulting in me getting a segmentation fault when running it. I am trying to read from an input of characters in that function. For the sake of helping me figure this out, I will post my other functions along with the fillArray function

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* standard header file */
#include "Assg6.h"

 void fillArray(int *array, int*count, char *buf){
*count = 0;
while(*buf){
    *(array++) = *(buf++);
    (*count)++;
 }
}

 void printArray(const int *array, int count, FILE *fpout){
int i;
for(i = 0; i <= count; i++){    
    fprintf(fpout, "%d ", *(array + i));
}
 }


int findMajority(int *array, int count, int *result){
int arrayb[count];
int i, counter, bcount = 0, ccount = 0, candidate, j;   
if(count % 2 != 0){
    int temp = *(array + count);
    for(i = 0; i <= count; i++){
        if(*(array + i) == temp){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter > (count/2)){
        *result = temp;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        count--;
    }
}
for(j=0; j <= count; j += 2){
    if(*(array + j) == *(array + j) +1){
        arrayb[bcount] = *(array + j);
        bcount++;
    }
}   
if(bcount == 1)
    candidate = arrayb[0];
    else
    findMajority(arrayb, bcount, result);

for(j=0; j <= count; j += 2){
    if(*(array + j) == candidate){
        ccount++;
    }
}
if(ccount > (count/2))
    return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

here is the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>        // standard header file 
#include <stdlib.h>       // for the exit() function 

#define LEN 80            // used in fgets() function 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   {
  FILE *fpin, *fpout;
  int a[LEN], count, majorityExists;
  char buf[LEN];
  int candidate;

  if (argc != 3) {
  printf("Usage: Assg6 InputFileName  OutputFileName\n");
  exit(1);
  }

  if ( (fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)  {
  printf("Input file %s cannot be opened\n", argv[1]);
  exit(1);
  }

  if ( (fpout = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
  printf("Output file %s cannot be opened\n", argv[2]);
  exit(1);
  }

  while (fgets(buf, LEN, fpin) != NULL) {  // for each line in the input file
  fillArray(a , &count, buf);
  printArray(a, count, fpout);
  majorityExists = findMajority(a, count, &candidate);
  if (majorityExists) 
      fprintf(fpout, "\thas the majority element %d\n\n", candidate);
  else
      fprintf(fpout, "\tdoes not have a majority element\n\n");
  }

  fclose(fpin);
  fclose(fpout);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug ? At which line it is complaining ?

Comment: Can you change your example to include a `main()` with a call to `fillArray()`? Right now, this is not a standalone example, which makes it nearly impossible to provide any meaningful assistance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Definitely familiarize yourself with your debugger.  This could be Visual Studio (on Windows), gdb (on Linux), or any of a million other alternatives.  Your debugger is your friend.  Please familiarize yourself with at least the basics of setting breakpoints, single-stepping through code, and viewing variable contents.

2) The only code that matters is:

a) Where you're allocating space for your array (e.g. `int arrayb[count];`), and

b) All the places where you're writing to or reading from that array.

```
  The moment you read data "off the edge" of your array ... game over.
```

3) BTW: "variable length arrays" (like "int arrayb[count]", where "count" is an input parameter) are probably a bad idea.  Please use a constant to initialize the array ... and least until you're comfortable with all the "basics".

IMHO...

PS:
"fillArray()" is *definitely* a good candidate to use to familiarize yourself with "single stepping" and "viewing variables" in the debugger :)